# jQuery .click vs .change

Tags: jquery

I'm just starting learning Javascript and jQuery (1 day in!). I ran into an issue yesterday that I eventually worked through, but have no idea why the change worked.

**TLDR; In jQuery, why does `.change` trigger a toggle/checkbox via an id tag when `.click` does not?**

Longer explanation below:

I'm hoping to understand why and find out if what I did was really the correct way to fix the problem I encountered.

I'm trying to create a list of items that can be toggled on and off and update the backend via AJAX.  When I built my sample list of two, when I would click one button, it would toggle ALL of the buttons.

I was calling via class (was not unique), so I moved each to a unique id and then the jQuery `.click` function stopped working.  After a few hours of beating my head against the wall, I changed from `.click` to `.change` - and it started working.

QUESTION:  Why does `.change` trigger fine using an id tag when `.click` does not?

Why doesn't this work as is?

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#toggle1').click(function() {
      var current_status = $('#engineer1').text();
      $('#engineer1').html('Changed 1');
    });
  });

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#toggle2').click(function() {
      var current_status = $('#engineer2').text();
      $('#engineer2').html('Changed 2');
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>

<input id="toggle1" type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Ready" data-off="Not Ready" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger">
<div id="engineer1">Should Change</div>

<input id="toggle2" type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Ready" data-off="Not Ready" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger">
<div id="engineer2">Should Change</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `click()` event doesn't work with both inputs because Bootstrap is overriding it (like already mentioned in Tom's answer) and changing the DOM for both toggle-elements - the `input` with the `id="toggle1"` is replaced with this:

```
<div class="toggle btn btn-success" data-toggle="toggle" style="width: 112.783px; height: 37.6px;">
   <input id="toggle1" type="checkbox" checked="" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Ready" data-off="Not Ready" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger">
   <div class="toggle-group">
      <label class="btn btn-success toggle-on">Ready</label>
      <label class="btn btn-danger active toggle-off">Not Ready</label>
      <span class="toggle-handle btn btn-default"></span>
   </div>
</div>
```

and, in addition, the input's style is set to `display:none;`.
In order to have it working with your example it's possible to set a `click()` event on the divs with the `class="toggle"` which are not in the DOM when the page is initially loaded using event delegation - the `click()` event is passed from a parent element of these divs which is already there when the page is loaded - `document`. This `click()` event is then attached to both divs with the class toggle. To get the corresponding input and its id, it's possible to use `children()` as the inputs are the first child elements of these divs.

```
 $(document).on( "click", ".toggle", function() { 
    var selected = $(this).children().attr("id");
    var selectedID = selected.substring(6);   
    $("#engineer" + selectedID).html('Changed ' + selectedID);
 });
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/azj9r2m6/)

Answer (score 0):

Your bootstrap plugins are overriding your commands somehow. I believe the .click event is changing your toggle is somehow executing and not your additional functionality.

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#toggle1').click(function() {
      var current_status = $('#engineer1').text();
      $('#engineer1').html('Changed 1');
    });
  });

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#toggle2').click(function() {
      var current_status = $('#engineer2').text();
      $('#engineer2').html('Changed 2');
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="toggle1" type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Ready" data-off="Not Ready" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger">
<div id="engineer1">Should Change</div>

<input id="toggle2" type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Ready" data-off="Not Ready" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger">
<div id="engineer2">Should Change</div>
```

Comment: But this - should - work alongside bootstrap, correct?  Can you think of a way to get them both to work?  Is `.change` a proper way to do it?

Comment: @JonathanPassmore I got it to work alongside bootstrap in this Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azj9r2m6/ and am about to make an answer with some explanations out of it.